# Rewrite javascript function into node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, rewriting

I have this function: (which is I guess abstract factory for creating javascript objects)

```
var $class = function(definition) {
    var constructor = definition.constructor; 
    var parent = definition.Extends;
    if (parent) {
        var F = function() { };
        constructor._superClass = F.prototype = parent.prototype;
        constructor.prototype = new F();
    }
    for (var key in definition) {
        constructor.prototype[key] = definition[key];
    }
    constructor.prototype.constructor = constructor;
    return constructor;
};
```

A use it for defining classes C/java syntax like with polymorphism and extending:

```
var Bullet = $class({

    Extends: GameObject,

    constructor: function(texturePath, x, y, ctx, direction, passable, player) {
        GameObject.call(this, texturePath, x, y, ctx, 1, 1, passable, new Array(8, 8, 0, 0));
    },

    isActive: function() {
    },

    getPlayer: function() {
    },

    update: function(dt) {
    },

    destroy: function() {
    },

    processCollision: function() {
    }
});
```

And then calling:

```
var bullet = new Bullet(params);
```

I tried to rewrite it into nodejs module like this:

```
(function(){
var $class = function(definition) {
    var constructor = definition.constructor; 
    var parent = definition.Extends;
    if (parent) {
        var F = function() { };
        constructor._superClass = F.prototype = parent.prototype;
        constructor.prototype = new F();
    }
    for (var key in definition) {
        constructor.prototype[key] = definition[key];
    }
    constructor.prototype.constructor = constructor;
    return constructor;
};
module.exports.createClass = function() {
    return $class();
}
});
```

And then call it with:

```
var c = require(__dirname + "\\Class");
var Bullet = c.createClass({
   Extends: GameObject,
    constructor: function() {}
});
```

But it doesn't work, can you please help me with rewriting?

**UPDATE**: I rewrited it from @Salem answer, but I lost extending and polymorphism in process.
In order to have extending I simply  have to write instead of

```
Extends: ParentClass
```

this:

```
Extends: ParentClass.constructor
```

I've expected that polymorphism would be something like:

```
// in class which is extended from ParentClass
ParentClass.method();

// in parent class adding line
module.exports.method = ParentClass.method;
```

But this is undefined. So where is the catch?

**FINALLY** I used mochiscript module for nodejs, it is even better syntax sugar with more object oriented functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `createClass` is a function without any parameter. Also you call `$class` without any paramter also.

You don't need to wrap all your code in a function, because everything you declare there won't  be accessible from outside unless you export it. So it should be something like this:

```
var func = function(definition) {
    var constructor = definition.constructor; 
    var parent = definition.Extends;
    if (parent) {
        var F = function() { };
        constructor._superClass = F.prototype = parent.prototype;
        constructor.prototype = new F();
    }
    for (var key in definition) {
        constructor.prototype[key] = definition[key];
    }
    constructor.prototype.constructor = constructor;
    return constructor;
};

module.exports.createClass = func;
```

This means that if you require this module as `X`, the only thing you can access is `X.createClass`, and not `X.func` or anything else.

Comment: And what If I want to acess methods from func? I want to call it in order to have polymorphism.

Comment: You can still access `func`, but by the name `createClass` (`X.createClass(something).someMethod()`). What I meant is that only the references you export are visible outside. If you defined another function named `func2`, unless you explicitly exported it you could not access it from the outside. So wrapping all your code in a function is not necessary here.